# The r function I have previously used successful no longer works

Tags: r, function, summarize

I am trying to create a summary for this data set

```
 Morph ID black white orange green
1      O  1     2     1      0     3
2      O  2     2     1      3     0
3      O  3     2     1      1     2
4      O  4     3     0      2     1
5      O  5     3     0      2     1
6      O  6     3     0      1     2
7      O  7     3     0      1     2
8      O  8     3     0      3     0
9      O  9     0     3      2     1
10     O 10     3     0      3     0
11     O 11     3     0      1     2
12     O 12     0     3      2     1
13     O 13     3     0      2     1
14     O 14     3     0      2     1
15     O 15     2     1      1     2
```

I created the summary below before with a data set that has the exact same format.

```
            n      mean       sd min Q1 median Q3 max percZero Choice        se   
sum.greenO 15 0.8666667 1.187234   0  0      0  2   3 60.00000 Orange 0.3065424  
sum.greenG 15 2.1333333 1.187234   0  1      3  3   3 13.33333  Green 0.3065424
```

I used the function Summarize() but this function is no longer working.
I need to create the same bar graph I made for this previous data set, which I can't do without "n", "sd", or "se". (I created "se" using "n" and "sd" - it didn't come with the initial function output).

I am confused about how a function can stop working? Is there an alternative function I am not aware of?

Please let me know if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Likely because it was a custom function, and you didn't run the code that creates the function (or load a package from which that function resides).

Comment: Also, the `Summarize()` I think you want is probably `summarize()` and is found in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

The following R packages on CRAN all provide a function called "Summarize" with a capital S:

```
> collidr::CRAN_packages_and_functions() %>% filter(function_names == "Summarize")
    package_names function_names
1        alakazam      Summarize
2          basket      Summarize
3          bayesm      Summarize
4       ChemoSpec      Summarize
5  ChemoSpecUtils      Summarize
6            cold      Summarize
7        dataMaid      Summarize
8          fastJT      Summarize
9             FSA      Summarize
10        GLMpack      Summarize
11        LAGOSNE      Summarize
12           lslx      Summarize
13         MapGAM      Summarize
14 MetaIntegrator      Summarize
15         NetMix      Summarize
16          PKNCA      Summarize
17        ppclust      Summarize
18            qad      Summarize
19  radiant.model      Summarize
20         ssmrob      Summarize
```

Of course it is not guaranteed you made the previous summary with one of them, but hopefully this helps you find the right one.